# Гифка в вордпрессе

Tags: wordpress

Пытаюсь добавить в шапку гифку. Если добавлять обычную картинку - все ок, а когда добавляю гифку, то ей автоматически прописывается display: none !important. Никак не могу решить проблему. Помогите плиз.
https://pastenow.ru/2K6SB

Comment: Работает javascript. Скорее всего, расширение браузера, которое блокирует гифки.

Comment: Да, спасибо большое, открыл в режиме инкогнито и заработало.

Comment: повбфвавбы за такое...

Comment: @SeVlad чего?)))

Comment: @KAGGDesign 1. любая неуправляемая анимация - зло. А тут вообще в шапке. 2. объёмы траффика.

Comment: @SeVlad это понятно. А что такое `повбфвавбы` ? ))

Comment: @очепятка :) [повбывавбы](https://yandex.ru/yandsearch?&text=повбывавбы). Руки бы отрубать за такое. По самую шею. :)

Comment: @SeVlad это просьба заказчика)) я тут не при чем...

Comment: Никто кстати не заметил что я двойной джекпот сорвал? Мой вопрос под номером 777777 , это просто успех )))